# DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string

Tags: datetime, postdate, plugin-amforms

I want to get the lates `postDate` of a List and format it for the `cache` tag

```
{% set latestSubmission = craft.amForms.submissions(
    { formHandle: 'reservation', order: 'dateCreated desc' }).datum('>= '~now).dateCreated().first()
%}

{{ latestSubmission }}
```

This Returns:

> Do., 07 Sep. 2017 10:32:05

But I want to pass it into the Cache Tag so I want to format it and write:

`{{ latestSubmission | date('c') }}`

This returns the error:

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (Do., 07 Sep. 2017 10:32:05) at position 0 (D): The timezone could not be found in the database

Why? Why can’t I reformat it when it is already returning a date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because `Do., 07 Sep. 2017 10:32:05` isn't in a valid PHP [Date/Time format](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) when you pass it into the `|date` filter.

Changing it to `07 Sep. 2017 10:32:05` should work.

Comment: But that means the `latestSubmission` tag which gets it's data from the am forms plugin saves the date in the wrong formate in the db? since there is no manipulaiton on my side ??? Or ist this a server config thing?

Comment: I'd guess it's an plugin issue, but not 100% sure.

Comment: I'll check back with the plugin dev

Comment: `c` is valid format for the `date()` function, it outputs in ISO8601 http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: @carlcs oops... my bad!

Comment: The plugin dev hasn't answered on my github ticket so far 